# Setting With Copy Warning when trying to change value from a column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-settingwithcopy-warning

I am trying to do the following.

```
df_county_outcomes['county'] = df_county_outcomes['county'].apply(lambda x : '0' + str(x) if len(str(x)) == 1 else str(x))
```

I get the correct result but the SettingWithCopyWarning will always be there. Can someone help? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It would be great if you can show the dataframe, as creating a basic dataframe with a ```county``` column with random data in it does not give me any ```SettingWithCopyWarning```, check your version of pandas, this could possibly be a issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to a few reasons. [This](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/) article helped me immensely.

TLDR is you can use `pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)` to suppress that warning if you are **certain** what you're doing is okay. In your case it looks like you can suppress the warning.